# Can the TP-Link Archer T4U AC1200 be used as a wireless access point?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-access-point

I've read that not all wireless adapters can be used as a wireless access point, so I was wondering if this [one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00JBJ6VG8) works. Also, is it compatible with Linux and hostapd?